# Scroll to without #

Tags: jquery, scroll

Is it possible to use instead of **#** char a **?** char for scrolling the elements?
So instead of:

```
<a class="scroll-to" href="#sec-1">Portfolio</a>
<section id="sec-1" class="section">
```

I must use:

```
<a class="scroll-to" href="?sec-1">Portfolio</a>
```

Script which handles the scrolling:

```
$(".scroll-to").click(function () {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top - ($("#nav-sticky").outerHeight())
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why that? Why not using `#`?

Comment: There are different concepts for `#` and `?`. The first is used usually for anchors, navigation pagination, some information... While the question mark refers to variables (understood by server-side). Is it possible? Yes, it is. But maybe not recommended since every thing has its own use.

Comment: change `this.hash` to `this.getAttribute('href')` instead.

Comment: Because I got task from analytics team to redo a scrolling links from # to ?. They cant track the link which is like www.url.com/#footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution, using data attribute instead of id.

https://jsfiddle.net/gnemeth/o96rL3qy/2/

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/gnemeth/o96rL3qy/2/
```